# Sap Custom Fiori App LPD_CUST Additional Information changing?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a custom fiori application in launchpad which is working. But when I enter the Launchpad in the GUI using **LPD_CUST** tcode, I saw that the application additional information part was **managed=FioriWave1**.

If I change this part **SAPUI5.Component=com.quotation** like that, I get the below error when the application starts in launchpad. What can be the reason? I couldn't find any relations?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a SAPUI5 version problem. What SAPUI5 version do you use in your Launchpad? Go to Console -> "sap.ui.version".

[sap.tnt.InfoLabel](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.tnt.InfoLabel) is available since version 1.54, which is very new. I guess your launchpad is using a lower version.